# Rewrite rules in Apache

Tags: apache

Can anybody tell me where to put Rewrite rules in httpd config file and tell me also how can I write rules in different file and include that file in httpd config file

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules in a separate file go in the hidden *.htaccess* file. This file goes in the public webserver's folder where you want the rules to apply and it is applied in a way that it respects *.htaccess* files on higher folder hierarchy.

For .htaccess files to be considered you need to add `AllowOverride All` in the Directory Tag where your server is configured.